# Where can I find Micro-USB B feedthrough adapters?

Tags: usb

Perhaps I am missing something, but I am finding it virtually impossible to find **Micro-USB type B receptacle** to **Micro-USB type B receptacle** feedthrough adapters. As I understand it, this is effectively the same as Micro USB type AB.

The application is plastic enclosure, which needs USB to power a Raspberry Pi.

[This is the only product I have found so far that meets these specifications.](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/usb-dvi-hdmi-connectors-adapters/377?k=&pkeyword=&pv166=1048&pv166=1215&pv166=1244&pv167=1104&pv167=1106&pv167=1111&FV=ffe00179&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=100)

Perhaps this confusion is a result of my misunderstanding the USB standard. In any case, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Might be hitting a snag because most panel mount adapters are going to come with wires already attached. [example](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3258?gclid=Cj0KCQjw0a7YBRDnARIsAJgsF3OTnIbYNh0E-W7Agdje_2SU0NSMZ6bf5boUaoJhRQpKWXqpaWrgMYEaAro3EALw_wcB).

Answer (score 1):

These are non standard cables, as usb normally does not allow female connector on cable. You can find plenty of then as micro usb extension cables or "panel mount" extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, but what would you be connecting to it on the inside?

As I understand, Raspberry Pi is powered via micro-B USB port, i.e. it acts as a "device" where USB is concerned. As such, you will be plugging USB-B cable into it, which has USB-A on the other side.

So, what you are looking for is USB-B to USB-A feed-through, which conforms to USB specification. Something [like this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/switchcraft-inc/EHUSBBABX/SC1837-ND/1832371). I am sure there should be micro-B versions too.

What you are missing is that per USB standard the cable is *always* directional: host side is A, device side is B.

The logic is simple: Your enclosure is a device when viewed from outside. So it has B receptacle. But the Pi inside the box is a device too, where box is concerned, so the Pi has B and box has an A for it.

Any adapters that conform to specification, including feed-trough, must not change the general agreement.

BTW, this is exactly the reason Pi has separate B for power even though it also has several A ports. Pi acts as "host" when you connect something like keyboard to it. Although I think it uses OTG chip connected to those, which is wrong, but that is another question altogether.

Comment: Always? Yeah, not always. OTG and usb AB connectors. Now usb c reversible connectors.

Comment: As does the RPi micro usb. It's for power and host and peripheral. It's OTG and used pretty much like otg is expected to work.

Comment: All true. Except you forgetting that OP specifically mentioned the goal is delivering power to Pi. As such it does not matter whether Pi port is B or AB, it would only confuse matters. Of course AB-to-A feed-through would preserve the entire port functionality, but it still will be A on the inside, which was my point.

Comment: @Passerby, it depends on which RPi is under question. Most common RPi-3B doesn't have OTG, while RPi Zero does. In any case one of u-B receptacles is used as a bold power jack, with no data signals nor ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with USB standard. RPi uses one of its micro-B receptacles just as a power jack. If you want your enclosure to have the u-B port extended using a feed-through connector, it won't really work, because you won't find any u-B to u-B cables.

All you need is a power jack of any type on your enclosure, not necessarily of USB type.

Comment: Any? https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+micro+extender&num=30&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnvc-Zq6rbAhViOX0KHWvaCZ8Q_AUICygC&biw=1236&bih=693